# What information identifies the file data at a path as being unchanged?

Tags: python, caching, python-3.x, memoization, stat

I want to memoize the result of a function that operates on the file data at a given path. How can I determine if the file data has changed since I last processed it?

I'm considering mapping a key containing [`st_dev`, `st_ino`, and `st_mtime`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/os.html#os.stat) to the results. Is this sufficient?

Comment: I doubt st_dev changes, st_ino means the file was replaced by another file, but you may need to known it, so I suggest st_ino + st_mtime

Answer (score 0):

The file size and a checksum of the file contents would go much further in determining uniqueness.

Comment: Checksumming is out of the question, processing the data myself is much cheaper than that already. I'm not looking for the naive file size/checksum combination here.

Answer (score 0):

Most application only looks at m_time, assuming that if it's unchanged so is the file. So that is clearly sufficient for most applications.